# EF Core DDD many-to-one relationship, foreign key is always null

Tags: domain-driven-design, many-to-one, ef-core-5.0

**Relation**: many products can belong to the same category. Have simplified the domain models to focus on the issue.

I'm using EF Core v5.0.

`Product` model class:

```cs
public class Product: Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    protected Product() { }

    public Product(string name, Category category): this()
    {
        Name = name;
        Category = category;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; }
}
```

`Category` model class:

```cs
public class Category: Entity
{
    protected Category() { }

    public Category(string name): this()
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Product configuration:

```cs
public class ProductConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Product");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
               .HasValueGenerator<StringValueGenerator>()
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(500);
        
        builder.HasOne<Category>().WithMany();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Category configuration:

```cs
public class CategoryConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Category");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
               .HasValueGenerator<StringValueGenerator>()
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.Name)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(255);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So having this configuration and domain models in place, when trying to insert some seed data the `CategoryId` property (shadow property created by EF Core, and not in the domain model) is always null.

```cs
public class ProductDbContextSeeder
{
    public async Task SeedAsync(ProductDbContext context)
    {
        var category = await context.Categories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "Test Category");

        if (category is null)
        {
            category = new Category("Test Category");
            await context.Categories.AddAsync(category);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        var product = await context.Products.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "Test Product");

        if (product is null)
        {
            product = new Product("Test Product", category);
            context.Products.Attach(product);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I have inspected the state of the entries right before the call to `context.SaveChangesAsync()` and it seems that the entities are in correct state as below:

When saving Category:

- Category -> Added

When saving Product:

- Product -> Added
- Category -> Unchanged

What am I missing? Appreciate any hints, pointers.

Thanks

Comment: After the first `SaveChangesAsync` call, `category` is unchanged, but that doesn't mean that the product-category association isn't established. The new product will have the new category's CategoryId as FK after saving. BTW, You can suffice with one `SaveChangesAsync` call at the end.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I was just testing out with saving separately. That's how it originaly was. However, after the SaveChanges is called, the CategryId isn't populated in the Product table.

Comment: I missed the getter-only properties. I don't think they are supported for reference navigation properties. It should at least have a private setter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#read-only-properties

Comment: Oh :/ Thanks for spotting it @GertArnold. That was it. At some point I had readonly properties, but had configuration using private backing fields. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually the problem is in your configuration - `builder.HasOne<Category>().WithMany();`, which is basically telling EF to ignore the navigation property (readonly or not). Of course it should be `HasOne(x => x.Category).WithMany()`

Comment: You're right @IvanStoev. Thanks